# eslint complaining about resolving paths

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint

I keep receiving the eslint error `import/no-unresolved` and am unsure as to how I fix it. I know this is related to babel, but I’m not sure how to get babel and eslint to play nice.

My babel.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }], '@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: [
    'babel-plugin-macros',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
    [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      {
        loose: true,
      },
    ],
    [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
      {
        useBuiltIns: true,
      },
    ],
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      {
        helpers: false,
        regenerator: true,
      },
    ],
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
      {
        async: false,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

… and my .eslintrc.js file

```
module.exports = {
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  extends: 'airbnb',
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  plugins: ['react', 'jsx-a11y'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  rules: {
    'object-curly-spacing': 2,
    'arrow-parens': ['error', 'as-needed'],
    'arrow-body-style': [2, 'as-needed'],
    'comma-dangle': [2, 'always-multiline'],
    'import/imports-first': 0,
    'import/newline-after-import': 0,
    'import/no-dynamic-require': 0,
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 0,
    'import/no-named-as-default': 0,
    'import/no-unresolved': 2,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    indent: [
      2,
      2,
      {
        SwitchCase: 1,
      },
    ],
    'space-before-function-paren': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/aria-props': 2,
    'jsx-a11y/heading-has-content': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control': 2,
    'jsx-a11y/mouse-events-have-key-events': 2,
    'jsx-a11y/no-autofocus': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/role-has-required-aria-props': 2,
    'jsx-a11y/role-supports-aria-props': 2,
    'max-len': 0,
    'newline-per-chained-call': 0,
    'no-confusing-arrow': 0,
    'no-console': 1,
    'no-use-before-define': 0,
    'prefer-template': 2,
    'class-methods-use-this': 0,
    'react/forbid-prop-types': 0,
    'react/jsx-first-prop-new-line': [2, 'multiline'],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': 0,
    'react/prefer-stateless-function': 0,
    'react/jsx-no-target-blank': 0,
    'react/require-extension': 0,
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'react/self-closing-comp': 0,
    'require-yield': 0,
    'import/no-webpack-loader-syntax': 0,
    semi: ['error', 'always'],
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      webpack: {
        config: 'config/webpack/development.js',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

The issue occurs for every type of import:
[image: screenshot of eslint errors]

Any suggestions?

#### EDIT

I’ve created a repository using the same eslint setup as I’m using in this project. It’s showing the same error I’m seeing.

https://github.com/brandondurham/eslint-test

Comment: Hi Brandon, There could be situations - how and what you are trying to import from the file system / modules. If you could post the usage where you get the error - might be useful. One thing you can try is in eslintrc file to add prop to ignore case senstivity "rules": {
   "import/no-unresolved": [
      2, 
      { "caseSensitive": false }
   ]
}

Comment: Added a screenshot showing eslint errors for all imports.

Comment: step 1: start reducing this to where your eslint is maybe 2 or 3 lines but you still get the bug. Then start reducing your babel config until it's a few lines. Then reduce your actual test case to running that config on a single file. Now you have an excellent [mcve] for Stackoverflow, where you'd done all the work that _you_ can do to drill down into what might be wrong, and others can immediately pick up for you. IF you haven't discovered the solution while forming that MCVE.

Comment: although I heavily suspect it's because you're saying you want ESLint to validate your code as ecmaVersion`6` instead of the `2018`. 6 doesn't have module support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to at the very least update your eslint config to say you want ES2018 (or newer) support, since you're validating modern JS with module imports:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  ...
};
```

Because from https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options we know that `ecmaVersion: 6` corresponds to asking ESLint to validate your code as ES2015, which predates ES modules, and so will correctly flag any `import ... from "..."` statement as an error.

I tried your github repo with a *heavily* reduced ESlint config:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  extends: 'airbnb',
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true,
    es6: true
  },
  plugins: ['react'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  rules: {
    'no-unused-vars': 0
  }
};
```

And that works just fine, so: start building it back up until it breaks, so you have a better idea of what really needs addressing.

Comment: This seems like the answer but unfortunately didn’t solve the problem.

Comment: Then you're still going to have to create an [mcve] and update your initial posting with that.

Comment: I’ve added a link to a small repo.

Comment: Remember that the idea for Stackoverflow is that the question has all the details - links to live demos or repos are fine, but only _in addition_ to showing that same code in your post, because external links turn into 404s. (future visitors who find your question tomorrow, or 10 years from now, should still be able use it as reference, irrespective of whether links are dead or not)

Comment: (having said that: that is a _huge_ eslint config, you definitely still want to start removing rules there until you find the one-or-few rule(s) that make the diference between seeing an error, and not seeing an error)

Comment: I've updated the answer with an eslint config that works fine, which is what you do when figuring out a [mcve]: if what you have breaks no matter how much you pare it down, work the other way around; start with something that works, even if it's almost nothing like what you had, and then build it back up to what you had bit by bit until you introduce the changes that break things.

Comment: You got it. Thanks so much for the help and advice.